# raspberry driver stepper motor 24v 2A

Tags: raspberry-pi3, motordriver

I need help because I know nothing about the field... I found a stepper motor that would suit me and that I would like to control by programming with a raspberry pi3 card. The specifications of this motor are 24v voltage and 2a current. I can't find a corresponding driver, does anyone know of one? Thanks in advance

I tried to find drivers with an input voltage of 24v and an intensity of 2A but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: You can try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ for this question. BTW keep in mind that you can use a driver for which that voltage and current are *within its limits*, it doesn't have to be an exact match. If it supports 3A that's fine, that means it survives at 2A.